# Cross frame Javascript - frames loaded from local (file://)

Tags: javascript, scripting, frame

I have two frames loaded from local filesystem with file:// URL. How can I access the document in the left frame from the right frame?
`parent.leftFrame.document` gives:

**"Error: Permission denied to get property Window.document"**

I went through several articles explaining [Same origin policy for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) but those didn't help with files loaded from local filesystem

The `document.domain` property for both of my frames are empty.

On Linux with Firefox 3.

Comment: Is the surrounding document or frameset also a file:/// ?

Comment: Yes, the frameset is also loaded from local file.

If the files loaded into the frames are in exactly the same folder then access to the other frame works in Firefox. Otherwise I got the "Permission denied" error. Isn't there a way to overcome this limitation in FF?

Comment: E.g. in Opera cross-frame JavaScript seems to work even if the files are in different directories.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found [security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy) preference in Firefox 
that solves the problem.

Needle in a haystack...

Comment: It is from this forum:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=782875&p=4080485